# Alternative to bind function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization, native, v8

So i was reading about Functional programming and Optimization of the V8 code, and i decided to check if the `bind` function is optimizable by the V8 ?

so i read the native javascript code and was hit by these lines of code,

```
 var newfn = function() {
    // Combine the static args and the new args into one big array
    var args = boundargs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    return fn.apply(self, args);
  };
```

this lines of code show clearly that the handling of the arguments object will cause that the returned function to be in-optimizable by the v8 according to MDN . 
so the question is their any NATIVE alternative to bind i can use ?

**Resources**

- [Optimization killers](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#3-managing-arguments)
- [Native code for bind function](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/infra/appengine/chromium_status/static/js/common/bind.js?q=bind.js+package:%5Echromium$+lang:%5Ejavascript$&sq=package:chromium&l=1) .
- MDN [mention arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) and the work around .
- [Rising stack - How to find Node.js Performance Optimization Killers](https://community.risingstack.com/how-to-find-node-js-performance-optimization-killers/)

Comment: Are you saying that this code is part of the built-in implementation of `.bind()` in V8?  If so, can you please provide a link reference?

Comment: There can be ways to avoid using `.bind()`, but those depend upon the actual programming usage context so we'd need to see that in order to offer those alternatives (such as arrow functions or closures).

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion that V8 cannot/does not optimize `bind()` or the bound function? Where is your proof?

Comment: that code looks incomplete. what is `boundargs`? what is `self`?

Comment: `in-optimizable by the v8 according to MDN` - why would MDN care about Chrome's V8?

Comment: @mscdex my prove is that the bind function manipulate `arguments` object according, i will add resource to my question .

Comment: @jfriend00 i did just now, edited my original question, and i know i can avoid using bind but i am asking if i have NATIVE JS alternative, that don't manipulate the `arguments` object .

Comment: @JaromandaX you missing the point sir, 
`var args = boundargs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));` 
this line of code is within the native code i just edited my question . 
according to MDN, Rising stack and Another resource i shared this cause hot functions (Function that is used a lot ) to be in-optimizable by V8 which is used in `Node.js`, `Chromium` and Opera  . 

any other code is irrelevant . 
anyway i shared the native code file, you can check what every variable mean their :)

Comment: yeah, I get what you are saying **now** that you've added useful information.

Comment: I can't find your code reference in this V8 repository: https://github.com/v8/v8.  I do find C++ code that looks like it could be `.bind()` related [here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/05e862f78398d8bbeacc7f9e19bbb41c408e709b/src/builtins/builtins-function-gen.cc).

Comment: @jfriend00 the link i shared is in javascript not C++, 
here is the link for the [native code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/infra/appengine/chromium_status/static/js/common/bind.js?q=bind.js+package:%5Echromium$+lang:%5Ejavascript$&sq=package:chromium&l=1)

Comment: Yes, I know that's Javascript.  I'm questioning whether that is actually the implementation of `.bind()` in V8.  I can't find your Javascript implementation anywhere in the V8 repository to show me that it's actually being used in V8.  The link in my previous comment looks like it might be the actual native code (e.g. C++) implementation of `.bind()` in V8 which would mean your optimization question is moot because the code reference you're looking at is not the actual implementation of `.bind()` in V8.

Comment: And, [this V8 code reference](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/0410e7e85032c9b49bd84f5a8ba71642264bce3f/src/builtins/builtins-definitions.h#L518) looks like it is defining `Function.prototype.bind` to use the C++ code `FastFunctionPrototypeBind` in my [previous code reference](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/05e862f78398d8bbeacc7f9e19bbb41c408e709b/src/builtins/builtins-function-gen.cc#L13).  So, I'm concluding that your `bind()` code reference isn't what V8 uses.  V8 uses a native code implementation that would not have the optimization issues you refer to.

Comment: And, here appears to be [another `.bind()` native code implementation](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/d9b54ff9882510e1843b8655e2b8320b0a30286c/src/compiler/js-builtin-reducer.cc#L1585) in C++ in the V8 repository.

Comment: @jfriend00 you made a valid point i will investigate ...

Comment: I just finished looking through 35 pages of search hits on bind in the V8 code base and could not find the Javascript code you referenced in your question.  I am doubting that that is actually used in modern V8.  Instead, it appears that `Function.prototype.bind()` is implemented in native C++ code and would not be subject to the optimization issues in your question.

Comment: @jfriend00 according to the link i shared about optimization killers, _This document will contain advice to avoid writing code that will perform significantly worse than expected. Specifically those patterns that cause V8 (relevant to Node.JS, Opera, Chromium...) to refuse to optimize the affected function._
i conclude from this that chromium use v8 and the filter i used in the search for this docs is chromium js code .

Comment: I'm familiar with that article on optimizations and how you have to be careful with the `arguments` object.  And, where do you get the `newFn` function from in your question and think that it has something to do with `Function.prototype.bind()` in V8?  That's the part of your question I don't get.

Comment: ok sir, i think you are right @jfriend00

Comment: @jfriend00 I think the "js-builtin-reducer" you linked is in fact the thing that *optimises* `bind` calls or bound functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try to summarize my comments into an answer.

Your question references some Javascript code that implements something like `Function.prototype.bind()` and it comes from a Chromium repository.  I honestly don't know the origin of that code, but when I look in the [V8 repository](https://github.com/v8/v8) which represents the currently active development on V8 (as best I can tell), that code you cite is nowhere to be found.  I looked through 35 pages of search hits on "bind" in the V8 repository and I searched for several of the somewhat unique words that are present in the comments in the code you referenced and I could find none of them in the current V8 repository.

And, there are several "native code" C++ implementations of `Function.prototype.bind` like functionality in the [current V8 repository](https://github.com/v8/v8), [here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/d9b54ff9882510e1843b8655e2b8320b0a30286c/src/compiler/js-builtin-reducer.cc#L1585) and [here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/05e862f78398d8bbeacc7f9e19bbb41c408e709b/src/builtins/builtins-function-gen.cc#L13).

So, I'm concluding that the bind-like Javascript code you reference from Chromium is not currently part of V8 and that V8 uses native C++ code implementations for `Function.prototype.bind` that do not have JS optimization issues.  So your question about finding a replacement is not really valid because it does not appear that the built-in implementatoin of `Function.prototype.bind` has any optimization issues like you are concerned about.

---

I am familiar with the optimization document you linked to and how you have to be very careful how you use the `arguments` object in order to avoid spoiling some Javascript optimizations.  But, that issue would not apply to an implementation of `Function.prototype.bind` that was done in native C++ code since those optimization issues only apply to code written in Javascript, not code written in C++.

Comment: very true, if it's implemented in C++ . 
The question in my mind now, does v8 compile the native JavaScript library or does it have a C++ code . 

I jumped to the conclusion that it may be compiling JS library because i red in one of the resource i sent that V8 used within Chromium so maybe the case V8 here is just a compiler, that compile native JS libraries in this case . 
You also have a point as i said before but none of which is Conclusive

Comment: V8 developer here. This answer is correct. The code quoted in the original question is not, and has never been, part of V8. (It's some polyfill used by some project hosted on chromium.org's servers; it's not even in the browser itself.) -- V8 has an implementation of `Function.prototype.bind` that is very highly optimized. -- Most of the "optimization killers" document is outdated now that V8 ships its new optimizing compiler, "Turbofan".

Comment: @HeshamAdel - Please see the previous comment from a V8 developer.